# Attribute Totals for Rain Gauges

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, python-script-tool

My goal is to create summary information to eventually present rain gauge totals attributes such as 1 day, 7 day, 10 day, 24 day and YTD totals.

I was wondering how to go about this in ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro so that I have 5 attributes with **site_id** (see picture) and **receive time** for that day having the maximum rain gauge accumulation which would equal 11 in sensor_class?

I assume I would have to query out the table for the given time periods and use the max statistic (receive_time) for that day to get the rain accumulation.

I am not quite sure how to query that either! I also would need a ModelBuilder for this so it can be easily replicated again or can be used for future readings.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So data_value is accumulated rainfall for each day? Why is first row 10 and next 0?

Comment: Yes, it also correlates with sensor_class=11. So I would need the max accumulation for 1/7/24/TYD for each given sensor_id.

Comment: Would I send you like a zip file of a table?

Comment: Yeah I don't think I'm allowed to share it

Comment: i really just need to know how to query the table so that i get MAX recieve_time for the given time periods in each site_id

Comment: I've been recommended summary stats but not sure how to go about that?

Comment: the data_value correlates with sensor_class=11. If sensor class is =10 doesn't matter its just null values the sensor picks up for some odd reason so I have to query around that to where I'm getting site_id, sensor_class=11, and max data_value and receive_time for the given time periods of 1,7,and 24 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters are a little unclear.  I believe what you really want is a summary value for each site_id listing the the max accumulations from the data_value field using on only the records that have 11 as the sensor_class value and you want the summary value derived based on four different date range record selections of received_time field values covering 1 day, 7 days, 24 days and all days in the given calendar year.

So you need a record selection where the sensor_class values equal 11 and the received_time date range covers one of the four time periods and then process a separate summary and then do this a total of 4 times to cover the 4 time frames.

Start with the Make Feature Layer Tool for a feature class or the Make Table View tool for a table, then use the Select Layer By Attribute Tool to select records where the sensor_class = 11 and the received_time falls within one of the date ranges, then use the Summary_Statistics tools with the site_id as the case field and the Max of the data_value field (which I assume is the accumulation).

The definition of the date ranges will depend on whether you want everything relative to the current date or relative to a date/time you specify for the end of the summary period.  If it is relative to the current date and you are using a file geodatabase you should be able to select records for the one day period using an expression like:

```
sensor_class = 11 and received_time <= current_date and received_time > current_date - 1
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was trying to ask but couldn't phrase it as clearly as I wanted! Thanks! However I'm a little confused about the query because it's not relative to the current date. The dates are from last years readings for one month. So I just want to know how to query out everything from Jan. 1 and then I would export that? And so forth for every period? Would all this be possible in a model builder? Or would I have to query out the table first and combine all the attributes in model builder?

Comment: I also am confused by the date ranges you are looking for.  Do you have data for 1/1/2017 through 1/31/2017?  If so I would have thought you would want the last day of the month included in all of the periods and then extend it backward for the other summary ranges.  If so, for a file geodatabase you would use for the 1 day period:  sensor_class = 11 and received_time <= date '2018-01-31 11:59:59' and received_time >= date '2018-01-31 00:00:00'  The Summary_Statistics creates a new output each time, so no need to export the selection on the layer.

Comment: Yes I have 31 days worth of data coming from 76 different sensors which give off readings every 15 min. So I need a summary table with rain accumulation totals for each site after the given periods of 1,7,24, days and year to date.

Comment: Theoretically you could have up to 31 different values for the 1 day readings, 25 values for the 7 day periods (1/1-1/7 through 1/25-1/31 shifting one day at a time), 8 values for the 24 day periods (1/1-1/24 though 1/8-1/31 shifting one day at a time) and 1 value for the calendar year period.  However, if you took the highest of each of those sets of readings all of the range values would be the same since they would be for highest day during the month for each station or you would have to choose the day giving the highest average across all stations.  So why do you want date ranges?

Comment: Oh no sorry I don't need date ranges just those specific days. I know that the last day of the range is going to be the highest. However I need to query the table out to where I am getting for example 1/1/17 only for each site and then from there run summary statistics for the max accumulation, or data_value. I just want to know how can I specifically get that script/query to be able to filter out the days I want?

Comment: Just to note each site_id is a different rain gauge so thats why I need the accumulative totals for the time periods.

Comment: It was not clear if the data_values accumulated over the month or reset each day.  It sounds like the values accumulate if the last day of the month is always the highest.  Anyway, you just have to chain together a bunch of separate queries and summaries in model builder changing the date range in each successive query any way you think works for you and set the next query as being dependent on a result from the preceding summary so they do not go out of order.  Alternatively, Python can do this with a cursor and dictionary in one pass using summary logic, but that takes advanced script skills

Comment: How would I go about this in model builder?

Comment: Read the third paragraph of my post.  It lists the 3 tools you need to chain together as a base model for a single date range.  Just keep adding the last 2 tools over and over for each new selection and summary output.  Add a parameter connection between the last summary and the next selection to make the selection dependent on a result from the prior summary to keep the tools in the correct sequence.  That is it, unless you want to come up with your own steps to pull together the multiple summary outputs into a single output (you are on your own for coming up with that)..

Comment: When I try to use make feature layer tool it wont let me input my table? Only a feature class

Comment: Then use to the Make Table View tool instead.  I assumed this was a feature class, not just a table.